# Google Sankey Diagram selection event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, sankey-diagram

I have a [Sankey](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey) diagram. 
**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kPS49/5/)** 
It seems, when I add a handler for the `select` event, it's not working.
 In the documentation there is the Event [section](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey#Events).

Comment: This is clearly a bug, does not work with version 1.1 either.

Comment: I realized in time.. also created an issue on [google.](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1654&thanks=1654&ts=1404387934)

Comment: What do you want the Sankey to do?  Checkout SankeyBuilder.com for a fully featured tool.