# Select event not fired on Google chart API for Sankey

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, dom-events

I'm trying to hook an event to a click on a Google Sankey diagram. The [Events](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey#Events) claim to include select but it doesn't fire on Chrome or Safari. onmouseover/onmouseout/ready seem to be hooked up if the event is switched in the code below -- I get something in the console log. That is switching the line:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
```

to

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', selectHandler);
```

shows the event listener is connected.

I've tried this on other newer chart types like word-trees and select is connected. What have I missed?

E.g.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'</script>   
<script type='text/javascript'>

google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages:['sankey']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);      
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'A');
        data.addColumn('string', 'B');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Mails');
        data.addRows([
            ['from elvis','frank', 285],
            ['frank', 'to wendy', 61],
        ]);
   var options = {width: 600};
   var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('thechart'));        

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

function selectHandler() {
    console.log('You selected ' + JSON.stringify(chart.getSelection()));
};

chart.draw(data, options);  
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='thechart' style='width: 600px; height: 300px;'></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Appears I'm not the first to ask this (some time ago) but still it's broken: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552612/google-sankey-diagram-selection-event?rq=1

Comment: Appears assigned as a known issue https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/1472

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set correct options:

```
 // Sets chart options.
 var options = {
        width: 600,
        sankey: {
            node: {
                interactivity: true
            }
        }
    };
```

I used this example https://jsfiddle.net/5mvx6bdr/
Works perfect :)

sankey: node: interactivity is set to false by default.

Comment: What if you wanted to trigger events based on link, say a -> c? I set link interactivity to true and when I clicked on the link it gives me row value. Is there an easier way to obtain the link relationship a->c?

Comment: Refering to the documentation: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getValue Updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/5mvx6bdr/4/

Comment: If you want to be sure what element was clicked (node or link) you will have to assign last selection to the variable and compare it with the current selection

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you are using the getSelection method for the Sankey chart event which returns an object. That object contains the node in the chart that you clicked on but you need to query the object in the right way to extract this information. I don't think it is possible to do things in a single line as attempted in the question above.

This is what worked for me when I had the same problem:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(){
var selection = chart.getSelection();
for(var key in selection) {
        var value = selection[key];
    console.log(value.name);    
    }   
alert('you selected '+value.name);
});
```

Comment: Please could you demonstrate this? I tried to fold in your example above at http://jsfiddle.net/ko1p4dzf/

Comment: Looks like you have two chart names in that file: 'thechart' and 'chart'. Try using a single name consistently and see if it works then.

Answer (score 0):

The top answer did not work for me.
However, setting *link interactivity* to true did the trick.

```
var options = {
 sankey: {
   node: {
    interactivity: true,
    colors: this.colors
   },
   link: {
    interactivity: true
   }
  }
}
```